# Does transformer's flux (due to load) need to obey Faraday's law

Tags: transformer, inductor, coil, magnetic-flux

I believe I have a good understanding of a transformer. But I may have a misunderstanding somewhere that is leading to absurd conclusions.

**My overall understanding**
If we ignore all losses and look at all the flux components in the core of a transformer with rated load, There is a small portion of flux (magnetization flux \$\Phi_{mag}\$) devoted to maintaining both PRI and SEC side coil's voltage. While there is a big clash of Titans between flux generated by the load on SEC (\$\Phi_{SecLoad}\$), and the flux generated by the source (trying to supply the load) on PRI (\$\Phi_{PriSupply}\$).

**Further thoughts and feeling ridiculous:**

1. Since \$\Phi_{SecLoad}\$ is only dependent on the load (or more
   precisely  \$I_{SecLoad}\$), and it is    being cancelled in the
   core all the time. I doesn't contribute to any    meaningful
   Faraday's law, or to say: \$N\frac{d\Phi_{SecLoad}}{dt}\$    doesn't
   really mean anything, it cannot manifest itself to be some
   voltage we can measure or model like \$\Phi_{mag}\$.
2. if we can discount various losses, \$\Phi_{SecLoad}\$ and
   \$\Phi_{PriSupply}\$ can go to infinity!? they will cancel each other
   anyways. So loss is the only real world constraint on
   \$\Phi_{SecLoad}\$ and \$\Phi_{PriSupply}\$?
3. The core can never saturate when supplied with rated voltage
   (discounting the polarization of the core during startup), again,
   because \$\Phi_{SecLoad}\$ and \$\Phi_{PriSupply}\$ cancels each
   other.

Comment: My own suspicion is that, I am relying too much on the equivalent circuit, and the flux doesn't really cancel each other in a way that they disappear, like "water is not flowing, but still in the pipe" sort of way.

Answer (score 1):

**Ignoring magnetization flux**

The magnetic flux produced by current **entering** a transformer's primary (due to the loading on the secondary) is perfectly cancelled by the magnetic flux produced by current **leaving** the transformer secondary: -

[image]

Picture from [here](http://stades.co.uk/index.html#transformers).

**Taking into account magnetization flux**

> *The core can never saturate when supplied with rated voltage*

In the real world the saturation of a core always happens but it's usually a "reasonable" amount that doesn't cause excessive heating.

Comment: I believe I agree with everything here, ie. fluxes canceling each other. Saturation due to non-linear BH curve. However, I am hoping if my 3 points listed in the questions can be either confirmed and debunked.

Comment: Hey! it's you, you were right, it was "leakage inductance". I made a very rudimentary mistake while trying to understand it.

Comment: Read my answer again - they are all either confirmed (1 and 2) or rebuked (3 partially).

Comment: So, various losses are the only thing limiting transformer's capability. Not part of the question, but regarding your picture there, shouldn't there be some sort of curvature on the step of Ip and Is?

Comment: Only if the transformer has leakage inductance and the one in the picture doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

In a real transformer, there are both external and internal impedance/resistances that limit current.

As the core sums up the primary and secondary fluxes, when that first little secondary current flows, the voltage across the primary winding DROPS.

This drop lets in additional current, exactly adequate to provide the secondary energy needed.

Comment: It is true that my question is based on steady state and discounts the transient interaction that incrementally load up the secondary. And everytime we have such transient little V drop on primary, the additional transient pri current should meet the Farady's law to make up for the V drop. Nonetheless, what do you think d (total secflux that cancels total priflux) / dt represent? or I was right saying it was a meaningless quantity